# Matching multi-line text

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

> [FONT=arial, helvetica]this
>
> is a  multiline text
>
> [/FONT]
>
> [FONT=arial,
>   helvetica] this is a single line comment[/FONT]

I'm trying to match the text inside the bbcode tags with this pattern:

```
\[FONT=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/FONT\]\im
```

But it only matches the single line text, why? I've even added the multi-line flag.

http://www.regexr.com/3b72f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of multiline flag you need single-line here.

```
/\[FONT=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/FONT\]/isg
```

Single-line modifier makes dot symbol match newline characters as well - it is exactly your issue.

Multiline modifier only makes beginning/end characters (`^` and `$`) match start/end of line.

Comment: Thank you. Was not aware of that flag... Will accept it in 4 mins

Answer (score 2):

```
\[FONT=([\s\S]*?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/FONT\]
```

You can also use this without any `flags`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/28